# MSSQL/SQL Query condition error

Tags: sql, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have this 2 following SQL Queries on my grails controller:

```
def query1 = sql.rows("select abc from table_one where cond = 1")
```

The return result from query1 gives me `[{abc=5}]`

```
def query2 = sql.rows("select req from table_two where abc = " +query1)
```

I am having an error trying to run query2 and I have no idea why.

the column name `abc` exist in both `table_one` and `table_two`, I am trying to fetch the value of `abc` from `table_one`, whereby `cond = 1`, and assign it to variable query1.

and with query2, I am trying to get the values of `req` from `table_two`, whereby the value of `abc` in `table_two` is equals to the value of query1.

any help on this?

Error message from query2:

```
Message:Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '[abc:5]'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join the table using `INNER JOIN`

```
select  b.req
from    table_one a
        INNER JOIN table_two b
            ON a.abc = b.abc
where   a.cond = 1
```

the following syntax is `ANSI SQL-92`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like the following query:

```
select  table_two.req
  from  table_one,
        table_two
 where  table_one.cond = 1
   and  table_one.abc  = table_two.abc
```

Joining the tables like that allows you to do it in one query, which is usually both more efficient and more correct (ie, the database table won't change between the two queries).

Comment: wow i didnt thought of that! thank you so much.
but theres an error: incorrect syntax near 'a'. 42000/102

Comment: @user1718890, it's possible you may have entered it wrong. That's valid syntax according to the standard _and_ MSSQL supports it as well. I'll change it to get rid of the aliases since that's something I usually do only for reduced typing.